# How can I create a scalable in-memory geohash?

Tags: redis, geohashing

I've been using Redis's Geohash capability. However, it doesn't seem this can scale well, as the index is implemented as a SortedSet, which cannot be partitioned. What is recommended for this problem? I will have frequent writes and reads both.

Comment: Did you try redisearch.io? https://oss.redislabs.com/redisearch/Overview.html#geo_index

Comment: Thanks. I just took a look at that. The section on "Scalable Distributed Search" basically does provide the answer to this question. Since asking this, I was starting to consider building what is referred to there as "Index Partitioning". It looks like you can also pay for something like that through RediSearch.